# Eval error - Wrong type argument: listp

Tags: emacs, elisp

The following code

```
(setq func 'concat)
(apply func "a" "b")
```

throws the following error

```
***Eval error*** Wrong type argument: listp, "b"
```

Why does `apply` take all arguments from the third position as arguments meant for 'func'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply` takes a list as its last argument, so these calls are correct:

```
(apply func "a" '("b"))
(apply func '("a" "b"))
```

To pass plain arguments, you can use `funcall` instead:

```
(funcall func "a" "b")
```

Eventually, you can also use `apply` as follows

```
(apply func "a" "b" nil)
```

or

```
(apply func "a" "b" ())
```

This is because `nil` and `()` are considered empty lists in Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 2):

The typical use of `apply` is to apply one function to a list of arguments and then "spread" that list over the arguments. On the other hand, `funcall` is only needed because elisp separates function and variable bindings.

```
(defun wrapped-fun (fun a b)
   "Wrapped-fun takes a function and two arguments. It first does something,
    then calls fun with the two arguments, then finishes off doing 
    something else."
   (do-something)
   (funcall fun a b)  ;; Had function and variable namespaces been the same
                      ;; this could've been just (fun a b)
   (do-something-else))
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply` takes a function and a list, so use

```
(apply func '("a" "b"))
```

Or just

```
(func "a" "b")
```